# How can i add user's location to a MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

Am currently working on an android project, am having issues adding user's location to the database. How can i add the location to a database, so i can retrieve in into the app? Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? getting current location? or writing data to a database? What have you done so far? Or you just want someone to do your work instead of you?

Comment: Do read our [what topics are allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guides. As of now, it looks off topic

Comment: I can get the users current location using the google play services api, i want to add that longitude and latitude to a mysql database. I have written the code that gets the location, just need help adding it to a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can store user location data in DOUBLE fields in a table, for example

`CREATE TABLE LOCATION (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, LONGITUDE DOUBLE, LATITUDE DOUBLE, USER TEXT);`